# Execute SQL Query in one servlet and Display result in table in another servlet....possible?

Tags: java, sql, database, servlets

I was writing MVC application using JSPs and SERVLETs...where i have to run a query to display contents of a table.I have done it in one servlet.I was thinking if it is possible to run SQL query on the required table in one servlet and display the result in another servlet?

Comment: It is possible, but you should explain the usage case where this would be useful to you. Do you want one user to send the query and another user, in another place with another browser, to see the results?

Comment: I have just started learning java web using servlets and jsp.I was writing a basic application in MVC.I want the logical code in one Servlet and the code which displays the content on the web page in another servlet

Comment: Then that would be an incorrect use of servlets. A servlet is an object that represents one complete transaction between browser and server - receiving user parameters, processing them, and returning a result to the browser. The separation into Model, View and Controller should be done from inside one servlet by passing the data around between objects that specialize each in its own task.

Comment: Then how can we separate Model,View and controller within one servlet?

Comment: You can see an example [here](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/). The servlet itself is the controller. It uses objects for the model, and then redirects to a jsp page for for the `view` part. Come to think of it, redirecting is technically like calling another servlet. So you could use another servlet for the view, but again, that's not a good way to do it.